# Are all 2-connected graphs planar?

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification, planar-graphs, graph-connectivity

I know that [all trees are planar](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3829434/show-that-all-trees-are-planar-without-using-eulers-formula-or-the-fact-that-al), and so now I'm wondering whether 2-connected graphs are necessarily planar. I would imagine that this is true given that all 2-connected graphs have an ear decomposition (Theorem 4.10 in [[1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1032606983)]), and that every ear decomposition I have seen is planar, like the following example (Figure 4.3, from [[1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1032606983)]):

[image: Ear decomposition]

So to be sure, I naturally tried to prove that ear decompositions are planar, but I'm uneasy about my proof:

---

*Proof*. Let $G$ be a 2-connected graph with an ear decomposition $E = G_0, G_1, \ldots, G_k$, where $G_0$ is a cycle and $G_i$ are ears for $1 \leq i \leq k$. We proceed by induction on the number of ears, with the base case being $k = 1$ ($E = G_0, G_1$), which is obviously* planar. So, we assume the statement is true for any graph with an ear decomposition having $k - 1$ ears, and we let $G$ have $k$ ears. Let $P = G_k\setminus \{u, v\}$, where $G_k$ is the "outer" ear of $G$ and $u, v$ are the end-vertices of $G_k$, and note that $G - P$ is planar by the induction hypothesis. $(G - P) + P$ is clearly* still planar, so $G$ is planar. $\blacksquare$

---

In particular, I'm uneasy about two aspects:

1. Are the jumps in logic that I made at the asterisks okay? How could they be stated better?
2. Am I characterizing ear decompositions correctly?

This is all. Thank you in advance for any advice!

### References

1: *Graphs and Digraphs, (7 ed.)*.

Comment: The nonplanar graphs $K_{3,3}$ and $K_5$ are $2$-connected; $K_5$ is even $3$-connected and regular of degree $4$.

Comment: Do you mean non-3-connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For any fixed $k\geq 1$, let $n\gg k$, let $F,H$ be two copies of a complete graph on $n$ vertices. Identify a copy of $K_k$ in $F$ and another one in $H$, and merge then together, akin to a [$k$-clique-sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique-sum) keeping all edges.

The graph has connectivity exactly $k$ and is non planar.

e.g. with $n=5,k=2$, the following graph is $2$-connected, not $3$-connected, and non-planar because it contains $K_5$.
[image]

The issue with your proof is that "outer" is not defined if the graph is non-planar.